# How to play FLV file in to Macromedia Flash Player?

Tags: flash

I can't get the following code to work:

```
 a="file="
 b=VIDEO_FLV_ROOT
 c=flv 
 d=" bufferTime=3 "
 e="autoStart=false "
 f="quality="&"'"& "high" & "' "
 path=a & b & c & d & e & f %>
<%'=path%>
<!-- <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0"
width="350" height="350" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <Param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <Param name="scaleMode"  value="showAll" />
    <Param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <Param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
    <param name="movie" value="<%'=VIDEO_FLV_ROOT%><%'=flv%>" />
    <param name="FlashPlayer" value="swf/doyoucamgood_player.swf"/>
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="buffertime" value="3" />
    <param name="autoStart" value="false" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="<%'=path%>" />
    <embed src="swf/doyoucamgood_player.swf" flashvars="<%'=path%>" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="350" height="350" allowScriptAccess="always" scaleMode="showAll" wmode="transparent" allowNetworking="all"/>
</object>
```

Using this code, I can get only player but it can't play file in it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I fixed some formating and changed the starting sentence, but if you want a answer you'll need to supply more information and be a bit more involved with the question than just fire and wait.

Answer (score 0):

In VBscript / VB.NET the ' is used for making comments (assuming the code you provided is in VB).

e.g. the following will return nothing since it's commented out.

```
<%'=VIDEO_FLV_ROOT%>
```

Change it to:

```
<%=VIDEO_FLV_ROOT%>
```